# User response.redirect to open link in new tab or window

Tags: asp.net

I want to use response.redirect to open page in new window or tab. I tried following things.
1)

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="createPanelBtn" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Resources/User.ico"     Height="23px" ToolTip="Create Interviewer Panel" CommandName="createPanelBtn" 
 CommandArgument="  <%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" Width="20px"  OnClientClick="aspnetFrom.target='_blank';"/>
```

2)

```
Response.Write("<script>window.opem('~/HR  Administrator/ConfirmationEntryForm.aspx?VacId=" + strVacId + "&CompId=" + strCompId + "&DeptId=" + strDeptId+")'</script>");
Response.End();
```

In none of the cases, I am able to achieve the goal. Please show me some way to do so...

Comment: Is the typo in 2) only here or in your source code, too? `"<script>window.opem" ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way of writing point (2) in your question which I suggest is use the literal control. Its the cheapest and easiest way to include/exclude scripts on web page. Like for e.g. say I have a login page where the user has to enter his credentials. If he enters the wrong credentials, the page should postback and give an alert message. For this I'd simply set the literal control which contains the script code to visible (`Visble=True`).

```
   <asp:Literal ID="ltrlInvalidLogon" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert('Invalid LogonID or Password provided.');
            </script>
        </asp:Literal>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnvd" runat="server" Text="View Details" OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('viewclient.aspx', 'windowname', 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Use your parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ImageButton id="createPanelBtn" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('page.aspx?ruerystring', 'windowname', 'width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes');" />
```

and for other parameter of the window.open function check below link

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works perfectly! It's a workaround but worked for me.

set the onclientclick property of the button that opens the new age as follows:

onclientclick="window.document.forms[0].target='_blank'; setTimeout(function(){window.document.forms[0].target='';}, 500);"

It uses a setTimeout to revert the change back to what it was!

Hopefully this can help someone!